# nifi ConvertRecord JSON to CSV getting only single record?

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform

I have the below flow set up for reading json data and convert it to csv using the convertRecord processor. However, the output flowfile is **only populated with single record** (I am assuming only the first record) instead of all the records.

Can someone help provide the correct configuration?

***Source json data:***

```
{"creation_Date": "2018-08-19", "Hour_of_day": 7, "log_count": 2136}
{"creation_Date": "2018-08-19", "Hour_of_day": 17, "log_count": 606}
{"creation_Date": "2018-08-19", "Hour_of_day": 14, "log_count": 1328}
{"creation_Date": "2018-08-19", "Hour_of_day": 20, "log_count": 363}
```

***flow:***
[image]

***ConvertRecord processor config:***
[image]

***JsonTreeReader controller config:***
[image]

***CSVrecordsetWriter controller config:***
[image]

***AvroSchemaRegistry controller config:***
[image]

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "demo_schema",
  "fields":
  [
    { "name": "creation_Date", "type": "string"},
    { "name": "Hour_of_day", "type": "string"},
    { "name": "log_count", "type": "string"}
  ]
}
```

***Flowfile content that I am getting:***

```
creation_Date,Hour_of_day,log_count
2018-08-16,0,3278
```

***what I need:***

```
creation_Date,Hour_of_day,log_count
2018-08-16,0,3278
2018-08-17,4,278
2018-08-18,10,6723
```

Hope I was elaborate to explain the situation and would appreciate if someone can help correct the configuration so that I get the complete data. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need the Avro configuration? Isn't there a JSONPath processor that you can query out the CSV columns?

Comment: Not sure how to use it in this case. But can you share a sample flow or template? and how to represent the Json path for my input Json feed?

Comment: I'm not sure how to comma delimit things, I would need to play around with it, but here's the docs https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#jsonpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing this [NIFI-4456](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4456) bug and has been fixed **starting from  NiFi-1.7** version.

> **To work around this issue:**

1.use `SplitText processor` with `split line count =1`

2.Then use `MergeContent/MergeRecord` processors (using Defragments as merge strategy) and make as **valid json array of messages**

if you are using Merge Record processor then Reader and Writer controller 
 services needs to be in Json format.

3.Then feed the **merged** relation to `ConvertRecord` processor.

**Flow:**
[image]

Starting from **NiFi-1.7+** version, we don't need to configure any thing new/additional in JsonTreeReader controller service as **NiFi is able to read json per line format** also.

**Update:**

***MergeContent Configs:***

if we are using MergeContent processor please configure the processor like this way as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

> Delimiter Strategy `Text`
>
> Header `[`
>
> Footer `]`
>
> Demarcator `,`

In addition i would suggest to use **MergeRecord processor instead of MergeContent processor** which will take care of creating a valid array of json messages.

Comment: Thanks @Shu. I will give this a shot! 
Alternatively is there a way to convert executeSql output to csv format ? If I can do that I directly extract before the flowfile reaches AvroToJson processor.

Comment: @StrangerThinks If you want to convert ExecuteSql output to csv then you need to use **Convert Record** processor there is no default way we can have output as **CSV file** from ExecuteSQL processor.

Comment: just tried the method, but still getting single record. I used merge Content processor with defragment strategy. I noticed the splitting and merging operation is working fine, but perhaps its still retaining the multi line format. How can I force the merge operation to join all json data into single line format?

Comment: @StrangerThinks Please check my update to the answer..!!

Comment: Perfect! the delimiter strategy did the trick! :) I will also try to use MergeRecord processor and test it out. Thanks for the help @Shu