# NiFi non-Avro JSON Reader/Writer

Tags: json, avro, apache-nifi

It appears that the standard Apache NiFi readers/writers can only parse JSON input based on Avro schema.

Avro schema is limiting for JSON, e.g. it does not allow valid JSON properties starting with digits.

JoltTransformJSON processor can help here (it doesn't impose Avro limitations to how the input JSON may look like), but it seems that this processor does not support batch FlowFiles. It is also not based on the readers and writers (maybe because of that).

Is there a way to read arbitrary valid batch JSON input, e.g. in multi-line form

```
{"myprop":"myval","12345":"12345",...}
{"myprop":"myval2","12345":"67890",...}
```

and transform it to other JSON structure, e.g. defined by [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/), and e.g. using [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) transformation, without writing my own processor?

**Update**

I am using Apache NiFi 1.7.1

**Update 2**

Unfortunately, @Shu's suggestion did work. I am getting same error.
Reduced the case to a single `UpdateRecord` processor that reads JSON with numeric properties and writes to a JSON without such properties using

```
myprop : /data/5836c846e4b0f28d05b40202
```

mapping. Still same error :(

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 3):

> **it does not allow valid JSON properties starting with digits?**

This bug [NiFi-4612](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4612) fixed in NiFi-1.5 version, We can use **AvroSchemaRegistry** to defined your schema and change the

**Validate Field Names**

```
false
```

Then we can have avro schema field names starting with digits.

For more details refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340069/defining-apache-avro-schema-fullname-in-apache-nifi) link.

> **Is there a way to read arbitrary valid batch JSON input, e.g. in multi-line form?**

This bug [NiFi-4456](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4456) fixed in NiFi-1.7, if you are not using this version of NiFi then we can do workaround to create an array of json messages with `,`(comma delimiter) by using.

**Flow:**

```
1.SplitText //split the flowfile with 1 line count
2.MergeRecord //merge the flowfiles into one
3.ConvertRecord
```

For more details regards to this particular issues refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956767/nifi-convertrecord-json-to-csv-getting-only-single-record/51957247) link(i have explained with the flow).

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting.
I am using NiFi 1.7.1. So do you mean that I _must_ use AvroSchemaRegistry to overcome the problem with digits in property names? I was not using the registry before (placing the schema into the processor/controller fields directly.
Having solved the porblem with numeric JSON properties would allow me using UpdateRecord (that supports batch processing) instead of JoltTransformJSON processor.

Comment: I mean, without the AvroSchemaRegistry it is not possible to change the behaviour e.g. by setting "Validate Field Names" to false?
Because I can invalid character exception as soon as property name in my Avro schema starts with a digit in NiFi 1.7.1.

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov, I don't think we can `validate field names` without 
 using **AvroSchemaRegistry** and i think using **UpdateRecord** processor to change the filed names will be good way of skipping **AvroSchemaRegistry**.

Comment: Thank you! Will give it a try

Comment: Please see update in the question. Unfortunately, using AvroSchemaRegistry didn't help :(